# Indexing symbol files with P4Index zero files found

Tags: perl, cmd, perforce, symbol-server

I am trying to setup a symbol server, and hence I need the symbols indexed to map to the source version.

I am running p4Index on folder where the solution resides.

my disc files and folders:

.\CalculatorDemo\bin\ where the output is produced
.\CalculatorDemo\CalculatorApp\ contains source
.\CalculatorDemo\CalculatorDll\ contains source
.\CalculatorDemo\CalculatorTest\ contains source

In my version control the path in the depot is:
//sw/Main/Internal/CalculatorDemo/

and my workspace is: 
c:\Projects\Dev\sw\Main\Internal\CalculatorDemo\

When I try to index it I get no files found..
    C:\projects\dev\sw\main\Internal\CalculatorDemo>p4Index -debug
    ---
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Server ini file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\srcsrv\srcsrv.ini 
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Source root    : C:\projects\dev\sw\main\Internal\CalculatorDemo
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Symbols root   : C:\projects\dev\sw\main\Internal\CalculatorDemo
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Control system : P4
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : P4 program name: p4.exe
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : P4 Label       : 
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Old path root  : 
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : New path root  : 
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Partial match  : Not enabled 
    ---
    ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Running... this will take some time...
    ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... indexing      C:\projects\dev\sw\main\Internal\CalculatorDemo\bin\x64    \Debug\CalculatorApp.pdb
    ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... zero source files found ...
    ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... indexing      C:\projects\dev\sw\main\Internal\CalculatorDemo\bin\x64\Debug\CalculatorDll.pdb
    ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... zero source files found ...
    ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... indexing  C:\projects\dev\sw\main\Internal\CalculatorDemo\bin\x64 \Debug\CalculatorTest.pdb

I cannot seem to get the hole through and get the file version info into the pdb's. - (I am doing this on my developer maschine, because I want to get the script working before I involve our build server)

Does anyone know (yes offcause someone does) how I can get the problem debugged/fixed. I probably has to do som perl debuggin or something. - I suspect that it could be a problem with not pointing to the rigth place 
on the perforce server...

Thanks in advance 
Kenneth

Comment: Please learn how to [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post properly!

Comment: What is `p4index`? Can you provide a link to its docs?

Comment: p4index is for indexing pdb files, so they refer to the correct verison in perforce, Its part of ms win 10 sdk.
I think after debugging it has to due with not loggin on to perfoce...

Comment: got it, it was due to a missing login.

Answer (score 0):

I just had something similar this morning.
I'll share my solution if it can help some.
The p4 environment variable weren't properly set in my case.
You can either set them manually or go in P4V, Connection -> Environment Settings..., don't change anything and press OK.
To make sure they're properly set, open a command prompt and type "p4 set", you should see a set of variables reflecting information on your current connection to Perforce.

Hope this helps.